# Site architecture for a document library linked to an arbitrary number of items in different lists

Tags: document-library, lookup-column

I am pondering the architecture of a site revolving around a document library of job reports of different services.

Each job report will be linked to the various services performed, ID of the service and sequence of the services is important

For each type of service, a specific list contains all the instances performed for all jobs

How can I allow the user to create a job report in the document library and append to it a service instance each time a service is performed for the same job?

My goal is to only use web interface or sharepoint designer without program writing to allow maintenance and limited administration by key users from our team.

So far I am looking into this as something similar to a purchase cart, where when needed, items are added from different inventory lists. I

[image: Job reports structure]

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use **Lookup** columns for this. There is a new feature with this kind of columns that lets you add to the view some fields from the linked list so, create a list for all services instances with a column for the service and another for the instance. Then, create a lookup column linked with the instances on the jobs list and making available to select multiple items. Configure it adding the service column to be shown on the views of your jobs list. That makes the user select the proper instances for the job and allows to see the service in the main view.

Comment: As the number of service instances in a job report is not fixed, how can I allow an arbitrary number of service instances to be linked to a job report?

Comment: With this solution uses are able to select multiple services but with no repetition.

Comment: I tried you proposal while enabling "Allow multiple values" in the lookup column settings, but this does not allow the behaviour of creating new instances in the looked up column. the goal is to allow the user to build up a report while editing the job report by adding new instances of services (think of a stack on services)

Comment: So, you mean you need users to add new instances at the same time they are adding new jobs? This is not allowed on SharePoint using ootb features.

Comment: One thing you can do is modify the new job form to add a link to add new services. Doing a trick on the link url passing "source" query string param equal to the current url, once the user adds a new service she will return to new job form making available to select. Take a try and let us know.